# Three two-run homers in the span of six batters

Tags: baseball, records

On June 2 2016 the [SF Giants did this against the Atlanta Braves](http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/playbyplay?gameId=360602115). The 5th innings for SF started as follows:

- AARON BLAIR PITCHING FOR ATLANTA
- Blanco walked.   0   0
- **Bumgarner homered** to left center (424 feet), Blanco scored.  2   0
- Span walked. 2   0
- **Panik homered** to right (382 feet), Span scored.  4   0
- Duffy hit by pitch.  4   0
- **Posey homered** to left (408 feet), Duffy scored.  6   0
- O'Flaherty relieved Blair

Has it ever been done before? This must be sort of rare, right?

Comment: The closest thing I can remember is Red Sox v Rockies 5-26-2016, when Clay Buchholz gave up three two-run homers with just two outs (and a half inning) between them.